# Spring: Is there a way to print out the time it consumes to create a bean?

Tags: java, spring

I googled but found no ways. My project is slow to start up so I want to see how long it is when creating a bean.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Use init-method attribute.**

```
<beans>
    <bean id="myBean" class="..." init-method="init"/>
</beans>
```

This will call the "init" method when the bean is instantiated.